# How do I Track App Uninstall / Remove Events for iOS using Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics

I need to get monthly uninstall count for iOS using Firebase. I know that for Android, there's app_remove event that I can use even if it's not really accurate, but it's enough for now.
From iTunesConnect or Playstore, they only give user retention data like how many user still use your app after x days, or daily uninstalls, which is not what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Right now, you can't track app uninstalls on iOS using Firebase Analytics. It's not a trivial change (I think most SDKs do this by keeping track of messages they get back from the APNs feedback service), but I'll put in a feature request on your behalf.

Comment: Yes, AppsFlyer is known to rely on APNs feedback. See this question for more details about the technique: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217603/iphone-app-uninstallation-notification

Answer (score 4):

Apple has added the deletion metrics recently by which we can see the number of uninstalls. We can add filters to find uninstalls for geographic range, app versions, by device and so on.
For reference: in iTunes connect app analytics in metrics under usage we can see the deletions.

Link : https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/whats-new/?id=iosdeletions

Comment: Note that this is only shown for users who have agreed to share their data with you.

Comment: @craigvl does this apply for crash data as well? Is there a reference? Thank you.