# How to know a particular user uninstall the app (iOS & Android)?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to know how to track uninstallation of the app, I know that with the Firebase we can get the total number of same. But not which is required by me.

Please let me know if there is any other SDK or could it be handle by the google analytics or FCM analytics.

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217603/iphone-app-uninstallation-notification

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of tools available individually on ios and on android, if you are looking for a common tool,  you Should Use FireBase Analytics https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en

Look for event - **app_remove**.

Firebase can be used in both iOS and Android and you can also log custom events to get specific information that you need.

Also refer to this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseanalytics/api/reference/Classes/FIRAnalytics

Comment: but how will I know whether a particular user is uninstalled or not. with some id or token where I can track it